# Javascript indexOf for an array of arrays not finding array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with nested arrays that looks like this:

```
var tw = [[3, 0], [11, 0], [3, 14], [11, 14]];
```

When I try and find if the array `tw` contains a passed in array, I always get a result of -1.

For example:

```
var test = $.inArray([3, 0], tw);
var test2 = tw.indexOf([3, 0]);
```

both return -1, even though the first object in the array is `[3,0]`
How do I find out if a specific array of arrays is contained in my array?

Oh, and I've only tested it on IE9 so far.

Comment: [indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality -the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - I do not see an array being target value in [inarray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) either

Comment: I suggested-edit the jQuery tag because `$.inArray` along with other minor changes, however I am not entirely sure if that is jQuery or if you want jQuery solutions (undo/improve/reject if that is the case)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because you're searching for a different object. `indexOf()` uses strict equality comparisons (like the `===` operator) and `[3, 0] === [3, 0]` returns false.

You'll need to search manually. Here's an example using a more generic `indexOf()` function that uses a custom comparer function (with an improvement suggested by @ajax333221 in the comments):

```
// Shallow array comparer
function arraysIdentical(arr1, arr2) {
    var i = arr1.length;
    if (i !== arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    while (i--) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function indexOf(arr, val, comparer) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if ( i in arr && comparer(arr[i], val) ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var tw = [[3, 0], [11, 0], [3, 14], [11, 14]];
alert( indexOf(tw, [3, 0], arraysIdentical) ); // Alerts 0
```

Comment: <deleted my spam>, see this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Da5GS/2/) (the other jsFiddle was wrong) of why you should use `if(i in arr&&comparer(arr[i], val))`

Comment: @ajax333221: Ahhhh, I thought you were suggesting using `for...in`. Sorry. Yes, that is definitely an improvement, although it makes no difference for the case of this particular question and I'd argue that explicitly setting an array property to `undefined` is asking for trouble. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are **objects**. [3, 0] does not equal [3, 0] as they are different objects. That is why your inArray fails.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're comparing two difference instance of array. Comparing objects returns `true` only if they're the same instance, it doesn't matter if they contain the same data.

In your case, you could use this approach:

```
var tw = [[3, 0], [11, 0], [3, 14], [11, 14]];

if (~tw.join(";").split(";").indexOf(String([3, 0]))) {
    // ...
}
```

Or something more ortodox like:

```
if (tw.filter(function(v) { return String(v) === String([3, 10]) })[0]) {
   // ...
}
```

Where the condition can be adjusted depends by the content of the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

**For infinite nested search:**

```
function indexOfArr(arr1, fnd1) {
    var i, len1;

    //compare every element on the array
    for (i = 0, len1 = arr1.length; i < len1; i++) {

        //index missing, leave to prevent false-positives with 'undefined'
        if (!(i in arr1)) {
            continue;
        }

        //if they are exactly equal, return the index
        if (elementComparer(arr1[i], fnd1)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    //no match found, return false
    return -1;
}

function elementComparer(fnd1, fnd2) {
    var i, len1, len2, type1, type2, iin1, iin2;

    //store the types of fnd1 and fnd2
    type1 = typeof fnd1;
    type2 = typeof fnd2;

    //unwanted results with '(NaN!==NaN)===true' so we exclude them
    if (!((type1 == "number" && type2 == "number") && (fnd1 + "" == "NaN" && fnd2 + "" == "NaN"))) {

        //unwanted results with '(typeof null==="object")===true' so we exclude them
        if (type1 == "object" && fnd1 + "" != "null") {
            len1 = fnd1.length;

            //unwanted results with '(typeof null==="object")===true' so we exclude them
            if (type2 == "object" && fnd2 + "" != "null") {
                len2 = fnd2.length;

                //if they aren't the same length, return false
                if (len1 !== len2) {
                    return false;
                }

                //compare every element on the array
                for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {

                    iin1 = i in fnd1;
                    iin2 = i in fnd2;

                    //if either index is missing...
                    if (!(iin1 && iin2)) {

                        //they both are missing, leave to prevent false-positives with 'undefined'
                        if (iin1 == iin2) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        //NOT the same, return false
                        return false;
                    }

                    //if they are NOT the same, return false
                    if (!elementComparer(fnd1[i], fnd2[i])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //NOT the same, return false
                return false;
            }
        } else {

            //if they are NOT the same, return false
            if (fnd1 !== fnd2) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //if it successfully avoided all 'return false', then they are equal
    return true;
}
```

**Notes:**

- supports infinite nested arrays
- handles sparse arrays correctly
- uses [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) checks

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R6FQ9/5/)

Comment: I spend hours figuring out that `NaN!==NaN` is `true`, and `typeof null` is `"object"`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$.inArray` and `indexOf` both use a shallow comparison using `===`.

Since the array you're passing is to `indexOf` not the exact same in memory as the one in your 2D array, `===` returns false. You'll need to do a deep comparison to find the array properly - from a quick glance at the jQuery docs, this is not available there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simple?

```
function indexOfCustom (parentArray, searchElement) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < parentArray.length; i++ ) {
        if ( parentArray[i][0] == searchElement[0] && parentArray[i][1] == searchElement[1] ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```